# Getting correct URL for number of rows in Parse.com database

Tags: parse-platform

This works from command line, but I want it to work in my java program. So I want to know the URL encoded full URL.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: {SECRET}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: {SECRET}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'count=1' \
  --data-urlencode 'limit=0' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Employee
```

returns:

```
{"results":[],"count":195}
```

I'm guessing that in my program I have to append **count** and **limit** to the URL. Do you guys know the URL representation of the above?

I've tried:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Employee%2Fcount%3D1limit%3D0
```

Best,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The ? must be added after the URL, then the parameters without %'s:

https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Employee?count=1&limit=0